# Loop through each row in range and fill in blanks if >1 blank

Tags: vba, loops

I'm trying to write a macro that will:

```
'loop through each row in a 4 column range
'count the blanks
'if there is more than 1 blank anywhere in the row, fill all blanks with "100" 
'if there is 1 or less blanks, leave everything blank
```

I've searched these boards a ton to find vba code that will loop through rows and have made a composite macro from things I've found here, that works OK except instead of filling in the blanks within each row, it fills in the blanks in Columns B and C (which appear before the range I've specified). Because B and C are both totally blank, I just get a wall of 100's.

Here's the code:

```
`Sub fillCellsUp()

Dim row As Range
Dim rng As Range
Dim BCount As Long
Dim nextrow As Long
Dim hundred As Integer
hundred = 100
nextrow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
Set rng = Worksheets("Worksheet1").Range("D2:G534")
Set row = Range(Cells(nextrow, 4), Cells(nextrow, 7))

For Each row In rng
    On Error Resume Next
    BCount = row.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Count 
If BCount > 1 Then row.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Value = hundred
nextrow = nextrow - 1
Next row

End Sub`
```

I've included an image of the actual Excel file I'm trying to fill:

Comment: Sorry- image didn't upload properly: http://tinypic.com/r/k573b/9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this?

```
Sub fillCellsUp()
Dim lr As Long, i As Long
Dim rng As Range
Dim BCount As Long
Dim hundred As Integer
hundred = 100
lr = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
For i = 2 To lr
    Set rng = Worksheets("Worksheet1").Range("D" & i & ":G" & i)
    On Error Resume Next
    BCount = rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Count
    On Error GoTo 0
    If BCount > 1 Then rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Value = hundred
Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

this works, just fill in you range dude

```
Private Sub this()

    Dim rng As Range
    Dim rcell As Range

    Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("d1:g" & ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Rows.Count)

    For Each rcell In rng.Cells
        If rcell.Value = "" Then rcell.Value = "100"
    Next rcell
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it'll work if you replace **row** with **rng** at the bottom:

```
Dim row As Range
Dim rng As Range
Dim BCount As Long
Dim nextrow As Long
Dim hundred As Integer
hundred = 100
nextrow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
Set rng = Worksheets("sheet1").Range("D2:G534")
Set row = Range(Cells(nextrow, 4), Cells(nextrow, 7))

For Each row In rng
    On Error Resume Next
    BCount = row.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Count
If BCount > 1 Then rng.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Value = hundred '<this should be rng rather than row
nextrow = nextrow - 1
Next row

End Sub
```